# Doctrine migrations unable to drop foreign key

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, migration

I'm new to Doctrine Migrations. I have made some changes to my entities and tested if the schema could be successfully created on a test database (myapp_test) and if my fixtures could be loaded. This seems to work well. I then go on the create a "diff" based on my development database `(myapp_dev)` which produces the following migration (omitted boilerplate for brevity):

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql", "Migration can only be executed safely on 'mysql'.");

    $this->addSql("DROP INDEX UNIQ_B3D683F5297EC529 ON my_table");
    $this->addSql("CREATE INDEX IDX_B3D683F5E6C3FCB5 ON my_table (item_id)");
    $this->addSql("CREATE INDEX my_table_idx ON my_table (item_id, user_id)");
}
```

The instructions seem to want to drop a unique and then create an index instead which are pretty much the changes I made to my entities. However, when I run the migration I get the following error:

```
Migration 20140331161825 failed during Execution. 
Error An exception occurred while executing 'DROP INDEX UNIQ_B3D683F5297EC529 
ON my_table':

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'UNIQ_B3D683F5297EC529': 
 needed in a foreign key constraint
```

If I understand the error correct it says there is a dependency on the `foreign key` I'm trying to `drop` in the first migration instruction. However, I have no idea how to go about fixing this.

How can I resolve the above migration issue?

Comment: Can you post the original entity/database schema and the target one? This does look like something's wrong in your model.

Comment: I think you might be right. I will investigate...